# Formula to show month if equal or greater than today's date

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

This is my pretty horrible code:

```
=IF((DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))>TODAY(),0,DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))
```

In cell A2 I start with this date: 01/09/2015

What I want to do is increment the month as I go down each line, but only show the date in that cell if I am actually in or past that month from today's date.

This would be the expected output:

```
01 September 2015
01 October 2015
01 November 2015
```

My main issue is, how do I get the result to be blank instead of showing a `0`. I've tried the following:

```
=IF((DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))>TODAY(),,DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))

=IF((DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))>TODAY(),'',DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))

=IF((DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))>TODAY(),"",DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))
```

None of these work.

Can anyone please make a suggestion, and as a bonus, see if there is a smarter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [Example Excel File](http://www.filedropper.com/datetest) I created.

Your third option will work fine for putting a blank in the cell using an empty string.

```
IF(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2))>TODAY(),"",DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2)))
```

Additionally, if you copy this down the column, eventually you will hit an error, if the previous row is blank. To prevent this from showing `#VALUE!`, you can use the [`IFERROR()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) function as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IF(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2))>TODAY(),"",DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,DAY(A2))),"")
```

If you have Excel 2007 or later, you can make use of the [`EDATE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5) Function and significantly shorten your formula. This function adds the specified number of months to the specified date. Here is the [`IFERROR()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) example using the [`EDATE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5) function:

```
=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(A2,1)>TODAY(),"",EDATE(A2,1)),"")
```

Comment: If they have 2007 and later it can be truncated to `=IFERROR(IF(EDATE(A2,1)>TODAY(),"",EDATE(A2,1)),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner good to know. I wasn't aware of that function. It seems rather specialized. I'll update my answer with that info.